# is it possible to pass "event" as argument to module?

Tags: system-verilog

```
module top();
    event e1;
    evnt i_evnt(e1);

endmodule

module evnt(input event e1);
  /* Program body  

  */
endmodule
```

when this modules complied it give error

> A Verilog keyword was found where an identifier was expected.

How to pass event as argument to module?

Comment: Your code seems to compile ok.

Comment: @AldoT i used irun version 10.20-s104 is there any issue related to simulator version.

Comment: @AkshayPatil It also works on EDAPlayground on both Riviera and ModelSim. Incisive 10 is a 4-5 year old version which didn't support the complete SV standard.

Comment: @Tudor i tried in EDAPlayground its working.

Comment: @Akshay Patil this seems to be a tool specific issue. EDAPlayground-VCS-2014 does not allow this. It throws an error reading, "Non-net variable 'e1' cannot be an input or inout port." BTW you can also replace event by wire/reg and change logic accordingly.